# How to resolve class inheritance error after interpretation in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

I am getting an error that I don't understand in isabelle when try to build a class heirarchy after a `global_interpretation`.

Here is a toy non-working example to illustrate.

```
theory mnwe

imports Main

begin

class natop =
  fixes natop :: "nat \<Rightarrow> 'a \<Rightarrow> 'a"

definition (in natop) list_double :: "'a list \<Rightarrow> 'a list"
  where "list_double xs = map (natop 2) xs"

global_interpretation semiring_1_natop: natop "\<lambda>n x. of_nat n * x"
  defines list_double = semiring_1_natop.list_double
  .

class special_list =
  fixes speclist :: "'a list"

class double_special_list = semiring_1 + special_list +
  assumes "list_double speclist = speclist"

end
```

The final class `double_special_list` raises the following error:

```
Type inference imposes additional sort constraint semiring_1 of type parameter 'a of sort type
```

Huh? Class `double_special_list` explicitly inherits from class `semiring_1` ...

Can someone please enlighten me on what I'm doing wrong?

**Update:**

If I drop `class special_list` and instead do

```
class double_special_list = semiring_1 +
  fixes speclist :: "'a list"
  assumes "list_double speclist = speclist"
```

I get error

```
Type unification failed: Variable 'a::type not of sort semiring_1
```

which again is a "Huh?" given the `semiring_1` superclass specification.

Comment: I am not a class specialist, but I believe that the problem ist the interpretation: `class double_special_list = special_list  +semiring_1 + 
  assumes "natop.list_double (\<lambda>n x. of_nat n * x) speclist = speclist"` works.

Comment: I am also not an authority on classes, but I always treated this as expected behavior. Inside the context of `double_special_list` the constant `speclist` will have the type `'a::{} list` (i.e. without any sort constraints), whereas `list_double` expects an input of the type `'a::semiring_1 list` (with a sort constraint). Given that only the type variable `'a` is allowed in the assumptions, I see an exception/error as the only plausible outcome.

Comment: @user9716869: I would have assumed the most "plausible outcome" would be for isabelle to resolve the imposition of the additional sort constraint by actually _imposing_ the additional sort constraint and inferring `speclist::'a::semiring_1 list` in the `double_special_list` context, and maybe throwing a warning instead a show-stopping error.

Comment: @MathiasFleury: Sure, but that works even if I comment out the `global_interpretation`. If this example were more than a toy, what I would want to do is flesh out the abstract theory of a `natop` and then have the `global_interpretation` automatically transfer those facts over to the case of a `semiring_1` with its own internal `natop`, without having to put `natop.X (\<lambda>n x. of_nat n * x)` everywhere.

Comment: @JeremySylvestre Given what you stated in the last comment, would it be acceptable to interpret natop inside `semiring_1`, e.g. by stating `sublocale semiring_1_natop: natop "λn x. of_nat n * x"  defines list_double = semiring_1_natop.list_double.` in the context of `semiring_1`? I believe, this is a reasonably canonical way of using interpretation with classes, e.g. see `semilatice_inf`.

Comment: @user9716869: Thanks, I'll give that a try. (I was using `global_interpretation` based on looking at `real_vector`.)

Answer (score 0):

OK, the following works (at least, doesn't throw any errors), but seems weird to me with the hidden `semiring_1` superclass declaration inside the `fixes` of class `double_special_list`. To be honest, I'm not really sure what the difference is between the code in my question and the code in this answer, and why the former is an error, but there you go.

```
theory answer

imports Main

begin

class natop =
  fixes natop :: "nat \<Rightarrow> 'a \<Rightarrow> 'a"

definition (in natop) list_double :: "'a list \<Rightarrow> 'a list"
  where "list_double xs = map (natop 2) xs"

global_interpretation semiring_1_natop: natop "\<lambda>n x. of_nat n * x"
  defines list_double = semiring_1_natop.list_double
  .

class double_special_list =
  fixes speclist :: "'a::semiring_1 list"
  assumes "list_double speclist = speclist"

lemma test:
  fixes a b c :: "'a::double_special_list"
  shows "a * (b + c) = a * b + a * c"
  by (simp add: algebra_simps)

end
```

Comment: I was slightly wary of recommending this solution. I am not aware of many instances of a sort constraint being applied explicitly inside a class context in the standard library, but I am aware of one instance where it caused problems: see clause 4 in https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2019-January/msg00046.html and a reply: https://lists.cam.ac.uk/pipermail/cl-isabelle-users/2019-January/msg00074.html. I have not investigated whether similar problems can occur for your use case, though.